# two-way table in R from a three-column table

Tags: r

I have read a tab-delimited file into R:

```
> var
          V1         V2     V3
1    sample1   sample18  99.97
2    sample2   sample3   99.97
3    sample3   sample36  99.96
4    sample4   sample2   99.96
5    sample5   sample16  99.96
6    sample6   sample22  99.96
..
```

I'm looking for a command like table(V1,V2), except I want the V1-vs-V2 values from V3. That's to say, I'm looking to transform this 3 column table into a distance matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
xtabs( V3 ~ V1 + V2, data=var )
```

Comment: +1 - well done for interpreting the OP correctly!